# Display JSON Array in laravel blade

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, laravel

I need to display the JSON data which is inside the column `extras_name` individually inside a input boxes with the value filled on edit

[image]

Here's the blade file codes

```
<div class="card">
        <h5 class="card-header">
            Manage Extras
        </h5>
        <div class="card-body">
            {{ $customProduct }}
            <br><br><br>

            <div class="optionBox">
                <div class="block main">
                    <div class="form-row pb-2">
                        <div class="col">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="extras_name[]" value="{{ $customProduct->name }}" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="extras_price[]" placeholder="Price">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <button type="button" class="remove btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="block mt-2 ">
                        <button type="button" class="add btn btn-success">Add Extras</i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's the Controller Edit function

```
public function edit($venue, CustomProduct $customProduct)
    {     
        $data = [     
            'customProduct'=>$customProduct,
        ];

        return view('manage.custom-products.edit')->with($data);
    }
```

Here's how the data is saved in the database

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show data in a table then you can use this code

```
<td>

 @foreach(json_decode($value->extras_name, true) as $extras_name)

     {{ $extras_name}}

   @endforeach
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all `json_decode` this
and then in `foreach` you can use that.

Blade File:

```
@if(!empty(json_decode($data->extras_name))) {{--JUST FOR CHEKING THAT IF THIS WAS NOT JSON OR THIS WAS NULL, THE ERROR NOT SHOWING--}}
    @foreach(json_decode($data->extras_name as $title=>$value))
        <label>
            {{$title ?? ''}} : {{$value ?? ''}}
        </label>
        <br/>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

it doesnt make sense to do that
instead you can show your values on list item below your input and when new value is added or removed refresh the list using ajax